# How to specify base href for scripts and styles in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm currently digging into Angular 2 and I'm having a problem with how styles and scripts are injected into `index.html` by the angular CLI `build` command (by that I mean scripts and styles defined within `angular-cli.json`).

The problem is that I'm running the app on a nested location, e.g.:
`http://domain.com/my_app`
While `<base href="/my_app">` can be set, the injected scripts and styles always point in `src` to the root domain. i.e. `/` instead of `/my_app`. This, of course, results in 404s while trying to view the page.

I'm serving the `/dist` directly.

**Nginx conf**:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    listen 80;

    location /my_app {
            alias /srv/www/my_app;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            gzip on;
            gzip_types text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;
    }
```

Where `/srv/www/my_app` consists of what essentailly `/dist` contains after running:

`ng build --environment=prod --base-href /my_app`

I can add prefix manually to styles and scripts declarations within the output `index.html` but that just seems to me as an unnecessary busywork.

Is there a way to specify the base href for injected styles and scripts declarations within `ng build` generated `index.html`? It would be even nicer if I could specify base href based on target environment, e.g.:

- `/my_app` for production
- `/` for development

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the same problem...

Comment: I never found a solution. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try to use the `--deploy-url` parameter when executing the `ng build` command ? This option indicates the *[URL where files will be deployed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options)*

So in your case you can try to run the following command:

`ng build --environment=prod --base-href my_app --deploy-url my_app`

Comment: should really be: --deploy-url my_app/

Answer (score 0):

Right Now for Angular v15

```
 ng build --base-href my_app
```

Also you need in Module

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my_app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

check https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF for more.